# Why is the following factorial code in Haskell working?

Tags: haskell, factorial

```
factorial n :: (Integral a) => a -> a
factorial n = n * factorial(n-1)
```

The above mentioned code works. For factorial(n=1)=1 but for factorial(n=0)=0. If this is the case then why does it work for any value of n(>0). My question shouldn't every output be 0?

Comment: Did you forget the base case? The code shown will never return 0; it will never return *anything*.

Comment: If there *is* a line `factorial 0 = 0`, then yes, it *would* always return 0. Typically, though, 0! is defined to be 1; are you sure the base case is not `factorial 0 = 1`?

Comment: thank you for the answer

Comment: I don't think you are running the code you think you are running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a correct Haskell code.

First of all, the type signature is invalid syntax - it should rather read:

```
fact :: (Integral a) => a -> a
```

Second, executing that function will not halt, as it does not have a "stop" condition.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the syntax error. I apologise for the mistake and thank you for the answer